# Progress Bar not showing with DownloadManager in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Hi everyone I am downloading APK file from my server and installing in device. It is downloading APK successfully and prompt to install screen. Now I want to show progress Bar same as play store while downloading APK from server.  Below is my code but it is not showing progress bar. How can I solve this ?

```
private void downloadAndInstall() {

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(app_url));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "zero_defect.apk");

        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);


        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        int bytes_downloaded = c.getInt(c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                        int bytes_total = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                        final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                downloadProgress.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                            }
                        });
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                            String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                            Log.d("ainfo", uriString);

                            if (downloadId == c.getInt(0)) {
                                Log.d("DOWNLOAD PATH:", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("local_uri")));

                                Log.d("isRooted:", String.valueOf(isRooted()));
                                if (isRooted() == false) {


                                    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Download");

                                    File file = new File(directory, "zero_defect.apk"); // assume refers to "sdcard/myapp_folder/myapp.apk"


                                    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); //for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {

                                        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                                    }
                                    Intent intent_install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
                                    intent_install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
                                    intent_install.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                                    intent_install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intent_install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); //dont forget add this line
                                    startActivity(intent_install);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App Installing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    //if your device is rooted then you can install or update app in background directly
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App Installing...Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/zero_defect.apk");
                                    Log.d("IN INSTALLER:", "/mnt/sdcard/Download/zero_defect.apk");
                                    if (file.exists()) {
                                        try {
                                            String command;
                                            Log.d("IN File exists:", "/mnt/sdcard/Download/zero_defect.apk");

                                            command = "pm install -r " + "/mnt/sdcard/Download/zero_defect.apk";
                                            Log.d("COMMAND:", command);
                                            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command});
                                            proc.waitFor();
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App Installed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because your code related to tracking progress is inside a receiver which is called when the download is already finished. What you want to do is start a new thread which will poll the `DownloadManager` for the information in a loop until it's finished:

```
final long downloadId = dm.enqueue(request);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(downloadId);

            Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int bytesDownloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
            int bytesTotal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                break;
            }

            final int progress = (int) ((bytesDownloaded * 100l) / bytesTotal);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);

                }
            });
            cursor.close();
        }

    }
}).start();
```